# How to "lock" a view's orientation during device rotation

Tags: ios, iphone

Let's say I have a view controller, call it ViewControllerPortrait, which is designed to display in portrait mode only. E.g.:

[image: ViewControllerPortrait]

When the user rotates the device to landscape, I don't want ViewControllerPortrait to ever re-orient itself to landscape, but I do want to present a new full-screen view. Let's call the full-screen view controller ViewControllerLandscapeFull. E.g.:

[image]

**What I don't ever want to see is this:**

[image: Don't do this]

The way I tried to do this is to have the window's rootViewController present ViewControllerLandscapeFull in full screen when it gets a `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
[navigationViewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

self.viewControllerPortrait = [[ViewControllerPortrait alloc] init];
self.viewControllerPortrait.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:self.viewControllerPortrait animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

And then in ViewControllerLandscapeFull I have:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
}
```

This works fairly well. Since ViewControllerLandscapeFull "prefers" landscape and has a `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` `modalPresentationStyle`, it only ever shows in landscape. By returning `landscape | portrait` for supportedInterfaceOrientations, device rotations back to portrait are allowed which happens when ViewControllerLandscapeFull gets `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and eventually `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO` is called on it.

The only problem I have is that during the rotation back to portrait, you can momentarily see ViewControllerPortrait in landscape orientation, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

ViewControllerPortrait does implement:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And I've verified that UIKit is calling it but it apparently has no effect. (The docs say that `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is only called on root view controllers and view controllers presented full screen, so I'm actually surprised UIKit calls it at all.)

FWIW, I'm working with the iOS 8 beta 5 SDK and building for 7/8.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Do you have ant tabbar or navigationbar in you app? I mean is your viewcontroller that you don't want to rotate is inside any tabbar or navigationcontroller?

Comment: Yes, what I've called ViewControllerPortrait above is part of a UINavigationController (a subclass, actually).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just beginning programming with iPhones, but maybe this will work...

Click on your project file > deployment info. Then unclick everything except portrait. This way rotating the device won't reorientate itself.

However, you can still test whether the device rotates or not with this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         NSLog(@"ROTATE to landscape");
         kitty.hidden = NO; 
         //(kitty is my imageview, hidden on load), once the device rotates to landscape, you can show your image.(or you can do something else)
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"ROTATE to portrait");
        kitty.hidden = YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Innovative solution, but it doesn't quite work for me. As soon as I present the new view controller with the preferred landscape orientation, ViewControllerPortrait's viewWillLayoutSubviews is called with a flipped bounds. I can also see it in landscape momentarily as before.

Answer (score 0):

```
houldAutorotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

The above methods don't get called of a viewcontroller if they are inside any tabbarcontroller of navigationcontroller. If these methods are declared inside tabbarcontroller or navigation controller then they will get called. In my case the viewcontrollers was inside navigationcontroller and the navigation controllers are inside a tabbarcontroller.

For solving this I make a class `FixedOrientationTab`, it is a subclass of `UITabBarController`, and a navigation class `OrientationEnabledNavigation`, it is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. Then I implemented `shouldAutorotate`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods inside `FixedOrientationTab` and `OrientationEnabledNavigation`.

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation : UINavigationController

@end
```

**OrientationEnabledNavigation.m**

```
#import "OrientationEnabledNavigation.h"

@interface OrientationEnabledNavigation ()

@end

@implementation OrientationEnabledNavigation

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
//    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FixedOrientationTab : UITabBarController

@end
```

**FixedOrientationTab.m**

```
#import "FixedOrientationTab.h"

@interface FixedOrientationTab ()

@end

@implementation FixedOrientationTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    //    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Then if you want to use navigation controller in your project then use `OrientationEnabledNavigation` and for tabbar `FixedOrientationTab`. After that if you implement `shouldAutorotate`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` these method inside your viewcontroller then they will get called.

Hope this helps.. :)